# Display SQL Data List in MVC

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, database, list

so I get the error:

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Contact' because 'Project.Models.Contact' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

for some reason. I am trying to display as simple as possible my data rows in my database table to my application.

Model:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model List<Project.Contact>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Contact</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var contact in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@contact.FirstName</td>
            <td>@contact.LastName</td>
            <td>@contact.Email</td>
            <td>@contact.Phone</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Project.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Sublime;Integrated Security=True");

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

             public ActionResult List()
        {
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Contact";

            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            var model = new List<Contact>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var contact = new Contact();

                contact.Id = dr.GetInt32(0);
                contact.FirstName = dr.GetString(1);
                contact.Lastname = dr.GetString(2);
                contact.Email = dr.GetString(3);
                contact.Phone = dr.GetString(4);

                model.Add(contact);
            }

            connection.Close();

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're sending the `query` string to `View` as the name a view.  Perhaps you meant to send `model` instead?

Comment: You are passing the query to the `View` method !

Comment: I changed that and I get error: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Contact' because 'Project.Models.Contact' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Also, What is `using (connectionString)` ??? Your code has lot of issues !!! In your view, you are looping through the Model. So make sure it is strongly typed to a collection of Contact

Comment: How do I make it strongly typed to a collection?

Comment: @Malphai I posted an answer

Comment: **Please do not keep updating(overwriting) the original question with new issues/errors.** You should add the new errors to the original question as needed or post a new question with the relevant details (minimum code to replicate the issues)

Comment: It finally worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, you are passing the `query` to the `View` method. You should be passing the List of Contacts after executing the query

So make sure you are returning a list of Contact objects to the View method.

```
List<Contact> model = new List<Contact>();   
string query = "SELECT * FROM Contact";

using (var conn=new SqlConnection("Put Your conn string here"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var m = new Contact();
                    m.FirstName = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));
                    //map other properties here as well
                    model.Add(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return View(model);
```

Since you are sending a list of Contact objects to the view (and looping through them, you should make your view strongly typed to a list of Contact

```
@model List<Project.Contact>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var contact in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@contact.FirstName</td>
            <td>@contact.LastName</td>
            <td>@contact.Email</td>
            <td>@contact.Phone</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: When I do @model List<Contact>, it says: "The type or namespace name 'Contact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?

Comment: Use the fully qualified name (including namespace). I updated my answer. It should be `@model List<Project.Contact>`

Comment: Now it says: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'TModel' because 'TModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Are you sure you have `@model List<Project.Contact>` and your action method is also sending the list ?

Comment: So I changed my code, take a look at the post I updated. Now I get the error: ""foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Contact' because 'Project.Models.Contact' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" in the View, everything else seems to work.

Comment: Do I have to have a parameter on my action method?

Comment: Your code should work fine if you follow what i wrote in the answer (pass a list of Contact objects to view and make the view strongly typed to `List<Contact>`. I just copied and pasted code from the answer and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never passing the model back to the view. you create a var model in your controller code but you need to pass that to the view where you have View(query), you also need to actually read the items from your sql query into the contact model list you've created. it should look something like this.

```
List<Contact> model = new List<Contact>();
while(rdr.read())
{
    Contact c = new Contact();
    //bind items to "c" here
    model.add(c);      
}

return view(model);
```

then in your view you can display the model as you have listed above if you change the model binding to this

```
@model List<Contact>
```

Comment: What do you mean: " //bind items to "c" here"

Comment: c.firstname = rdr.getvalue(0); and so on. you actually have to read your sql out into the object you've created, then add that object to the object list.

Comment: I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I think you might be in a bit over your head. but you can do a few things for that.... c.firstname = rdr.getstring(0) or c.firstname = convert.tostring(rdr.getvalue(0));    these also have to be in the order you read them from sql. so you should not do select * from table but rather select [firstname],[lastname], etc. from table

Comment: @Malphai have a look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldatareader to understand how to get the values from SqlDataReader.

Comment: So I changed my code, take a look at the post I updated. Now I get the error: ""foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Contact' because 'Project.Models.Contact' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" in the View, everything else seems to work.

Comment: have your Contact class inherit from IEnumerable.. that should more or less do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the point of the framework.  ASP.NET MVC isn't built to query a database and do the work of translating result sets to displayable web pages with no other processing, though it is designed to make integration with the code that does the work easier.

Here, after you execute

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You need to add code that reads what is in the reader and move that data to the model.  Something like

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Contact contact = new Contact {
        FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString(),
        ...
    };
    model.Add(contact)
}
```

Then, send the populated model to the view, where you can actually write the data on the view you are constructing.

Comment: So I changed my code, take a look at the post I updated. Now I get the error: ""foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Project.Models.Contact' because 'Project.Models.Contact' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" in the View, everything else seems to work.